# Unknown system variable when opening phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Comment: Could you also please let us know what MySQL version you have installed?

Comment: specify the version of mysql and phpmyadmin

Comment: mysql-5.7.14                php-5.6.25

Comment: what is your phpmyadmin version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is how I fixed it:

Upgraded mysql to latest version: http://www.tecmint.com/install-latest-mysql-on-rhel-centos-and-fedora/
After the upgrade mysql service couldn't start. Here's the fix:
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql_upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Go to Shell (In xampp at right corner, third one)

**Enter**

```
mysql // Hit enter

SET lc_messages = 'en_US'; //Hit enter
```

**Restart Mysql**

Comment: no change in the result

Comment: Had you restarted ?

Comment: yes,but of no use